Como puedo copiar un archivo y cambiarle el nombre automáticamente en Power Automate?
Estoy buscando una forma de como copiar un archivo que tengo guardado en una biblioteca y cambiarle el nombre automáticamente, pero no sé como hacerlo con Power Automate.
Esto sería para un sistema de clientes que estoy creando, donde cada vez que creas uno aparecen  5 carpetas con 5 archivos (estos archivos son con los que tengo problemas, porque no quiero que tengan el mismo nombre que el original, que mis plantillas).
He mirado muchos tutoriales de Youtube, pero hay mil cosas que no me aparecen a mi en mi sistema para poder hacer lo que ellos y no soy capaz de encontrarle solución.
Gracias por la ayuda.

Si, al crear un cliente, estás creando 5 carpetas con 5 archivos ¿como las estas creando? Con Power Automate?
Si editas tu post y pones imágenes de lo que hace tu flujo de power automate podremos ayudarte mejor.
